# Calculating the Jacobian determinant of the solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $x(t),v(t),f(x(t))\in\mathbb{R}^3$ then consider the following system of ODEs
\begin{align}
\dot{v} &= f(x)-v \\
\dot{x} &= v \\
\end{align}
with initial conditions $x(0) = x_0$ and $v(0) = v_0$. I would like to study how the Jacobian determinant $\left|\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}\right|$ evolves in time. This is essentially how a volume in the coordinates $x$ changes w.r.t time.

This is what I have done so far: Letting $X = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}$, then by Jacobi's formula we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}|X| &= |X| \, \text{tr}\left(X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X\right).
\end{align}
Differentiating once more with respect to $t$ gives
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|X| &= \frac{d}{dt}|X| \, \text{tr}\left(X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X\right)+|X| \,\text{tr}\left(\frac{d}{dt}X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X\right)+|X| \,\text{tr}\left(X^{-1}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}X\right)\\
&= |X|\left( \text{tr}\left(X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X\right)^2-
 \,\text{tr}\left(\left(X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X\right)^2\right)+
 \,\text{tr}\left(X^{-1}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}X\right)\right)
\end{align}
Now here is a step I am not entirely sure about: use the fact that
$$X^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}X = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial x_0} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
and similarly for the term with the double time derivative. Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|X| &= |X|\left( \text{tr}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2-
 \,\text{tr}\left(\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2\right)+
 \,\text{tr}\left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right) - \text{tr}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)\right)
\end{align}
Finally, another step that I'm not entirely sure about: aren't $v$ and $x$ independent of each other? I.e., $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$? If so does this then just reduce down to the following second order ODE in $|X|$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|X| = |X| \nabla\cdot f(x).$$
So if $f(x)$ is divergence-free, then $|X|$ depends linearly on $t$? And if the divergence of $f(x)$ is constant, then $|X|$ is oscillatory? This feels wrong! Please help!